# Regex com STD::REGEX em C++

Tags: c++, regex

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em C++ que necessito pegar algumas informações de uma String utilizando Expressão regular, estou utilizando uma expressão regular que usei no PHP perfeitamente, mas no C++ retorna em branco.

```
const std::string s = "{{ teste }}";
std::string r = "{{((.)+)}}";

std::regex rgx(r);
std::smatch match;

if (std::regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), match, rgx)){
    std::cout << "Number of maths: " << match.size() << "\n";
    for(int i=0; i < match.size(); i++){
        std::cout << "match: `" << match[i] << "`\n";
    }
}
```

No PHP ficava assim e funcionava perfeitamente:

```
$print_value = '/{{((.)+)}}/';
$var_get = "{{ teste }}";
preg_match($print_value, $var_get, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$piece = explode($formatches[0][0], $var_get);
.
.
.
```

O que será que está ocorrendo de errado? Outras expressões que eu uso funcionam perfeitamente.
Grato desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que esta ocorrendo de errado? **PHP**, esta linguagem dinâmica torna tudo muito simples, e ate corrige erros que talvez você nem perceba.

#### Problema

- `{` e `}` em REGEX é um [*reserved character*](http://www.morevisibility.com/images/blogs/google-analytics-filters-and-filtering4.jpeg), o que o PHP deve estar fazendo é um cast automático para literal, pois apos o `{` é esperado um quantificador `0-9`.

O PHP deve estar interpretando sua REGEX como `/\{\{((.)+)\}\}/` por este motivo.

#### Solução

Altere sua REGEX no C++ (linguagem tipádo) para `\{\{((.)+)\}\}`.

#### Nota

- Não a necessidade de criar `(.)+`, se seu intuito é pegal qualquer caractere, assim você apenas esta criando um grupo a mais. Basta `.+`.

Comment: Fiz esta modificação e o resultado foi o mesmo. Eu gerei esta expressão regular no site regex101.com e como lá funcionou achei que não tivesse problema das chaves.

Comment: @PedroSoares eu não entendo de C++, então creio que você deve verificar se nesta biblioteca não a necessidade de ter as barras ( `/REGEX/`) de inicio, fim.

Comment: Não ah, pois outros Regex que eu fiz, como este <code>(@for\(.*\))</code> funciona sem barra. E com barra é gerado um erro de syntax.

Comment: Resolvi o problema. Como eu estava utilizando aspas duplas, o C++ estava considerando o "\" como barra de escape e não estava repassando para o REGEX. Coloquei duas barras para serem repassas e funcionou. Ficou assim: \\{\\{(.+)\\}\\}

Comment: @PedroSoares Quem bom :D , de fato também não notei isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado por vossa ajuda.