# Regex correto em C++ retornando 0

Tags: c++, regex

Caros,

Criei uma expressão regular para instruções MIPS. Foi uma trabalheira danada, mas consegui. Pelo menos no [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) funciona, mas no C++ não. Eis o código com a expressão alguns exemplos de string com instruções que devem ser aceitas:

Código:

```
bool regexOk(string str){
    regex express{"[a-z]{2,4}[\s](([\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\d]\,\s[\d]*\([\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\d]\)|(\$szero\,\s[\d]*\([\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\d]\)|(-?[\d]*\,\s[\d]*\([\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\d]\))))|([\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\d]\,\s|(\$szero\,\s|(-?[\d]*\,\s)))([\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\d]\,\s|(\$szero\,\s|(-?[\d]*\,\s)))([\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\d]|(\$szero|(-?[\d]*))))"};
    return regex_match(str, express);
}
```

Strings:

```
lw $t0, 0($t7)
srl $t0, $t0, 1
addi $t1, $t7, 28
sll $t0, $t0, 2
add $t1, $t1, $t0
lw $t1, 0($t1)
addi $t1, $t1, 1
lw $t0, 0($t7)
sll $t0, $t0, 2 
addi $t2, $t7, 28
add $t2, $t2, $t0
sw $t1, 0($t2)
lw $t0, 0($t7)
addi $t0, $t0, 1
sll $t0, $t0, 2
addi $t1, $t7, 28
add $t1, $t1, $t0
addi $t2, $szero, -1
sw $t2, 0($t1)
```

Sim, a expressão ficou imensa e difícil de ler, mas no [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) funciona (rs), então imaginei que no C++ funcionaria também. Ela não está perfeita, mas serve para o propósito atual. Basicamente, ela pesquisa pelos seguintes grupos:

- instrução registrador, endereço

ou

- instrução registrador, registrador, registrador

Estes registradores podem ser também uma constante ($szero) ou um valor inteiro.

Como o regex do C++ funciona? Tem algo errado na expressão? Se não, qual seria o motivo do erro?

Comment: Olá acho o problema está nas barras, o regex de C++ deve estar identificando o \ como escape veja esse exemplo aqui no [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123262/regex-com-stdregex-em-c?rq=1)(leia principalmente os comentários da resposta aceita), e este no [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) repare o uso das barras.

Comment: @DiegoFerreira, eu havia visto essa resposta em minha pesquisa, mas não acho que seja o caso, pois as barras que estou usando são todas invertidas intencionalmente para o escape ou para os metacaracteres do regex (\s para espaço branco, etc.). Parece que na resposta que vc sugeriu, o erro era no uso de /, ao invés de \.

Comment: eu reescrevi o seu código fazendo que cada vez que ele encontrasse a sua expressão regular, ele circulasse com [ ], a saída foi [ lw $t0, 0($t7) ] para cada linha da string, é mais ou menos isso que voce quer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com relação a sua expressão regular você deve usar `\\` ao invés de `\`, com relação ao código o erro está no uso de `std::regex_match`, segundo a documentação encontrada [aqui](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match), ele só procura por correspondências completas veja o caso abaixo extraído do site que mencionei na seção Notas:

Como o `std::regex_match` considera somente correspondências completas, a mesma expressão regular pode fornecer correspondências diferentes entre `std::regex_match` e `std::regex_search`:

```
std::regex re("Get|GetValue");
std::cmatch m;
std::regex_search("GetValue", m, re);  // retorna true, e m[0] contém "Get"
std::regex_match ("GetValue", m, re);  // retorna true, e m[0] contém "GetValue"
std::regex_search("GetValues", m, re); // retorna true, e m[0] contém "Get"
std::regex_match ("GetValues", m, re); // retorna false
```

Segue um exemplo onde é feito o uso de regex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool regexOk( const string&, const regex& );
void print_regex( const string&, const regex& );

int main()
{

    string str = "lw $t0, 0($t7)\nsrl $t0, $t0, 1\naddi $t1, $t7, 28\nsll $t0, $t0, 2\nadd $t1, $t1, $t0\nlw $t1, 0($t1)\naddi $t1, $t1, 1\nlw $t0, 0($t7)\nsll $t0, $t0, 2\naddi $t2, $t7, 28\nadd $t2, $t2, $t0\nsw $t1, 0($t2)\nlw $t0, 0($t7)\naddi $t0, $t0, 1\nsll $t0, $t0, 2\naddi $t1, $t7, 28\nadd $t1, $t1, $t0\naddi $t2, $szero, -1\nsw $t2, 0($t1)";

    regex expression( "[a-z]{2,4}[\\s](([\\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\\d]\\,\\s[\\d]*\\([\\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\\d]\\)|(\\$szero\\,\\s[\\d]*\\([\\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\\d]\\)|(-?[\\d]*\\,\\s[\\d]*\\([\\$][(a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t)][a|t|p|[\\d]\\))))|([\\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\\d]\\,\\s|(\\$szero\\,\\s|(-?[\\d]*\\,\\s)))([\\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\\d]\\,\\s|(\\$szero\\,\\s|(-?[\\d]*\\,\\s)))([\\$][a|f|g|k|r|v|s|t][a|t|p|\\d]|(\\$szero|(-?[\\d]*))))" );

    cout << boolalpha << regexOk( str, expression ) << endl;
    print_regex( str, expression );
}

bool regexOk( const string& str, const regex& expression )
{
    if( regex_search( str, expression ) ){ return true; }
    return false;
}

void print_regex( const string& str, const regex& expression )
{    
    string new_str = regex_replace( str, expression, "[$&]");
    cout << new_str << endl;
}
```

Comment: agora sim, entendi o que vc queria dizer na primeira vez. Eu pensei que bastava uma barra invertida para ele entender como caratere de escape. Muito obrigado, meu caro! Agora funfou.

Comment: E também essa diferença entre o regex_match e o regex_search, que desconhecia. vlws mesmo!